# DataTrigger with Property = ItemControl.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger

I Am having some trouble getting this binding to work.  I have several objects within SettingCollection that all have an enum property.  I want to generate a control based on what the value of this is.  But when I check this value with a data trigger it does not work.

Can anyone provide some insight into how i can accomplish this?

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckboxNode">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Status}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextboxNode">
            <TextBox Text="Badgers"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SettingCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="checkbox">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsControl.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CheckboxNode}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="textbox">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsControl.ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextboxNode}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.Style>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Is Type an enum property in your viewmodel? are checkbox and textbox possible values of enum? if i were you i would make a conveter with type and return with primitive value (int,bool, etc) because i think your datatrigger won't recognize your value of enum. Or (in DataTrigger tag) you should use for example Value="{x:Static myenum:Type.checkbox}"> with your enum namespace:xmlns:myenum="clr-namespace:YourEnumNamespace;assembly=YourAssembly" (in your main window tag)

Comment: @PéterHidvégi Yes "Type" is a public property on the object SettingNode which is contained on SettingCollection

Comment: @PéterHidvégi it appears that no matter what i have in my datatrigger the itemscontrol is showing "Tugboat.Nodes.SettingNode" for each item in the collection instead of the templated checkbox/textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Type property is in SettingNode class, and SettingCollection is a collection of SettingNode objects, then your binding in the Datatriggers is incorrect. DataTriggers will look for Type property in ItemsControl DataContext (class with SettingCollection). Try to use DataTemplateSelector https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!